# mysql WITH GRANT OPTION behave strange

Tags: mysql

when I use the user `user1`, here is user1's privileges:

```bash
# in user1:
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@localhost                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `user1`@`localhost`                                            |
| GRANT SELECT ON `school`.`COURSES` TO `user1`@`localhost`                            |
| GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `school`.`STUDENTS` TO `user1`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now I run the commands:

```sql
-- in user1:
GRANT INSERT ON school.STUDENTS TO 'user2'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT UPDATE ON school.STUDENTS TO 'user2'@'localhost';
```

what i want to do is grant privileges of `INSERT` & `UPDATE` on `school.STUDENTS` to `user2`, allowing user2 to pass the INSERT privilege but not the UPDATE.

But then when i switch to user2 and check its privileges:

```bash
# in user2:
mysql> show grants;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user2@localhost                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `user2`@`localhost`                                                                         |
| GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `school`.`STUDENTS` TO `user2`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

why both INSERT & UPDATE have the GRANT OPTION??

i expected that INSERT has the GRANT OPTION while UPDATE don't.

any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

> if you have the UPDATE privilege for the grant tables in the mysql system schema, you can grant any account any privilege

Backward relation works too, it seems (remember about INSERT INTO .. ODKU and REPLACE INTO). Hence when you grant UPDATE to the table with GRANT OPTION then you grant GRANT OPTION to INSERT implicitly. And MySQL reports this in the final grants.

> i expected that INSERT has the GRANT OPTION while UPDATE don't.

You cannot, it seems.

Comment: thank u for answering!
`Hence when you grant UPDATE to the table with GRANT OPTION then you grant GRANT OPTION to INSERT implicitly.` 
I can realize this.
but... what i actually did is grant INSERT to the table with GRANT OPTION.  not the UPDATE.
UPDATE can implicitly bring GRANT OPTION to INSERT, but in turn it should not be that?

thanks.